# jquery datatable oTable.$ works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the latest version of the jquery plugin [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) and I tried to implement their selectable row and deletion [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html) into my project. My solution works correctly in Firefox but not in Chrome.

So in my partial view I create my table;

```
    loadSlideShowTable = $("#LoadTable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sType": "date-euro", "aTargets": [5] },
        { "sType": "date-euro", "aTargets": [4] }]
    });
```

and in my event handler for the row-clicking, I've got the following:

```
    console.log(loadSlideShowTable);
    loadSlideShowTable.$(".LoadTableRowSelected").removeClass("LoadTableRowSelected");
```

In FireFox the console.log returns:

```
jQuery(table#LoadTable.dataTable)
```

In Chrome the console.log returns:

```
[<table id=​"LoadTable" style>​…​</table>​]
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '$'
```

EDIT: It also works in IE and the console.log returns:

```
LOG: [object Object]
```

So I think the issue here is that Chrome doesn't seem to 'know' that $("#LoadTable") is a datatable object.

Comment: Do you have somewhere where we can see this in practice? Also, it looks like you should probably use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`. That's what your error seems to suggest.

Comment: Try switching `$` to `jQuery()` and/or use `jQuery.noConflict()`. You can also wrap you code in closures and pass in jQuery, such as `(function($){ $('#now_you_have_$_back inside');})(jQuery);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't delete my question, I'll just post a response with how I fixed it.

I closed all my chrome sessions, reopened my app, and tried again. It worked as it should after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try $(loadSlideShowTable.(".LoadTableRowSelected")).removeClass(xxxxx)

you want the elements with the class LoadTableRowSelected in a jQuery wrapper, adding it directly after the dot doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. I got more errors and FireFox flipped out when it hit the line in question!

Comment: Hmm.. weird. I closed all my chrome sessions and just tried out my original code again and it worked. I'll flag a mod to delete the question.